# Що означають слова: вдуплятися, віддуплятися, роздуплятися

Tags: значення-слів, сленг

Час від часу зустрічаю ці слова, але ніяк не можу знайти їх переклад або значення - ні в одному доступному мені словнику їх немає. Ось кілька прикладів з книги Сергія Жадана «Депеш Мод»:

> Нарешті Чапай **віддупляється** і лаштує нову папіросу.
>
> […] але ніхто не **вдупляється**, що це за інвалід і що це за патефон у нього тут на платформі […]

Comment: «Віддупляється» – приходить до тями, «не вдупляється» – не може зрозуміти, збагнути. «Роздуплятися» багатозначне, значення дуже залежить від контексту (як і у всіх цих слів), основні значення: 1) те саме, що «віддуплятися»; 2) збагнути реальний стан речей, як воно є насправді; відкинути стереотипи, нав’язані суспільством, та почати жити життям вільної людини. Посилань не маю, тому буде коментар.

Comment: Вдуплитися - це синонім вкурити. Тобто зрозуміти суть тези.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Словники

[Світлана Пиркало «Перший словник українського молодіжного сленгу»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Pyrkalo_Svitlana/Pershyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoho_molodizhnoho_slenhu/) (1997):

> **віддуплятися** *див.* **дуплитися**
>
> ---
>
> **дуплитися** не розуміти: *я йому пояснюю, а він сидить і дуплиться*

<sub>Update: О, бачу, Artemix [вже додав](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1215/4) те саме і ще статтю НДІУ; мабуть, слід вточнити його відповідь, а з моєї відповіді першу частину прибрати. Щоб не дублювати.</sub>

#### Походження

Можливо, мають російське походження. Принаймні аналогічні слова зафіксовані в деяких словниках («[вдуплять](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)», «[раздуплиться](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)») і в розмовній російській мові я чув їх частіше. Хоча, може, й навпаки.

#### Значення, на мій погляд

В словнику Світлани Пиркало, на мій погляд, пояснення неправильне.

Слова з коренем *-дупл*-, на мій погляд, мають значення «розуміти», «усвідомлювати» (а не «не розуміти», «не усвідомлювати»). Просто в недоконаному вигляді (а особливо з деякими префіксами) вони мають відтінок незавершеності (чи занадто тривалої тривалості).

З мого досвіду:

- *грубе* **вдупля́ти** (недок.) і **вдупли́ти** (док.) — розуміти, брати до тями («щось ти занадто довго таку просту річ вдупляєш»; «ну, вдуплив нарешті?!»);
- *грубе* **вдупля́тися** (недок.) і  **вдупли́тися** (док.):

  1. Те саме, що *вдупляти* і *вдуплити* без *-ся*  («щось ти занадто довго в таку просту річ вдупляєшся»).
  2. Ретельно вдивлятися в щось [можливо, намагаючись зрозуміти]; вилупитися, вирячитися, витріщитися («що ти вдуплився на мене?!»).
- *грубе* **дупли́ти** (недок.):

  1. Розумітити, брати до тями («що, зовсім не дуплиш?!»).
  2. Занадто довго брати до тями, замислюватися, рефлексувати («поки він дуплив, крадій вже втік»).
  3. Ретельно вдивлятися в щось [можливо, намагаючись зрозуміти].
- *грубе* **дупли́тися** (недок.) — те саме, що *дуплити* без *-ся*.
- *грубе* **роздупля́ти** (недок.) і **роздупли́ти** (док.):

  1. Розуміти, брати до тями (на відміну від *вдупляти* і *вдуплити*, частіше про ситуацію в цілому, а не про щось конкретне); прокинутися, усвідомити ситуацію.
  2. Пояснювати щось комусь («я цьому бовдуру вчора півночі інтеграли роздупляв, а він все одно — анічичирк; точно завалить іспит»).
- *грубе* **роздупля́тися** (недок.) і  **роздупли́тися** (док.) — те саме, що *роздупляти* 1 і *роздуплити* 1 без *-ся*.

Comment: Я звідкись всю дорогу уявляла, що цей синонімічний ряд походить від [*дупло*](http://sum.in.ua/s/duplo) в переносному значенні.  Напр., *дуплитися* - заховатися в дуплі (як у дитячій грі "я в хатинці"), не розуміти; *роздуплитися* - висунутися з дупла, зрозуміти. Схоже, мої здогадки - чудовий приклад для *хибної етимології*?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, чому ж, цілком правдоподібно. Але яка з версій правильна — я не знаю. (Я лише стверждую, що слово є і в російській; і оскільки воно, здається, порівняно нове, а не праслов'янське, то, відповідно, хтось у когось його запозичив.)

Comment: А після відповіді @Artemix версія з доміно тепер мені більше імпонує, бо щойно згадалось жаргонне - *дупля не відбивати* [1](http://www.dimaname.ru/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-9/), [2](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8C), що за значенням схоже на *не віддупляти(ся)*.

Answer (score 6):

[Стаття](http://dspace.nau.edu.ua:8080/bitstream/NAU/20087/1/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%2020%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA.pdf) із збірника наукових праць НДІУ дає таке означення:

> Намагатися щось зрозуміти – **вдуплятися**, в’їжджати, втикати,
>   роздуплятися.

[Словник молодіжного сленгу](http://docplayer.net/33922418-Pershiy-slovnik-ukrayinskogo-molodizhnogo-slengu-ukladach-svitlana-pirkalo-zibrano-1997-roku.html)

> **дуплитися** не розуміти: *я йому пояснюю, а він сидить і дуплиться*

Щодо походження - схоже що походить від слова "дубль" через жаргон, де "дуплитися" - ходити у доміно з "дупля" (кістка що має однакову кількість крапок на обох частинах), або скористатися правилом що дозволяє виставити декілька "дуплів" у [доміно](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/3314/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) або у грі [у карти](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/14461/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F).

Comment: Я звідкись всю дорогу уявляла, що цей синонімічний ряд походить від [*дупло*](http://sum.in.ua/s/duplo) в переносному значенні.  Напр., *дуплитися* - заховатися в дуплі (як у дитячій грі "я в хатинці"), не розуміти; *роздуплитися* - висунутися з дупла, зрозуміти. Схоже, мої здогадки - чудовий приклад для *хибної етимології*?

Comment: Версія з доміно тепер мені більше імпонує, бо щойно згадалось жаргонне - *дупля не відбивати* [1](http://www.dimaname.ru/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-9/), [2](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8C), що за значенням схоже на *не віддупляти(ся)*.

Comment: Можливо версія щодо "дупла" як основи породила дуплити, вдуплити тощо. Для подальшого словотвору хибна етимологія не стає завадою, а навіть навпаки.

Comment: Наразі, зібравши докупи усі варіанти з відповідей,  я схиляюсь до логічності такого ланцюжка: дубль - дупель - не відбивати дупля (все з доміно) - не віддупляти(ся) з похідними (вже в ширшому значенні). Але все ж бракує обгрунтувань.